# Display a cursor on QTextEdit in QT4.8.5

Tags: c++, qt, qt4.8, qcursor

I am newbie working on QT. Basically I am creating a QTextEdit box in QT and I want the Cursor to display at initial position. 
[image]

My Simple Code is :

```
    #include "mainwindow.h"
    #include <QApplication>
    #include <QLabel>
    #include <QFont>
    #include <QtGui>
    #include <QPixmap>
    #include <QTextEdit>
    #include <QTextCursor>
    #include <QLineEdit>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {

        QApplication a(argc, argv);
        MainWindow w;
        w.setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
        w.setStyleSheet("background-color: yellow;");
        w.show();

        QTextEdit *txt = new QTextEdit();
        txt->setText("Text 1");
        txt->setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
        txt->setFocus();
        txt->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255,      200);");
        txt->setGeometry(10,20,100,30);
        txt->show();
        return a.exec();
}
```

This creates a simple Text box on a window w.

I am not using mouse or a keyboard because it for a embedded Hardware board.

But after displaying the text the cursor should be displayed.

I am tried various method to get cursor displayed on QTextEdit like :

```
QTextCursor cursor;
QTextEdit *editor = new QTextEdit();

QTextCursor cursor(editor->textCursor());
cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::Start);
cursor.setPosition(5);
cursor.setPosition(9, QTextCursor::KeepAnchor);

txt->moveCursor(QTextCursor::End,QTextCursor::MoveAnchor);
txt->setCursorWidth(20);
txt->setTextCursor(cursor);
```

But none of the method displays cursor. I have done through most of the posts in SO.

Can anyone help? Thank you very much.

P.S : No solutions obtained in QT forums till now.

Comment: You seem to be missing at least `return a.exec()` at the end of your main()

Comment: I have added return a.exec() but forgot to paste it while copying here. I have edited my code. Thanks

Comment: The documentation for http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#setFocus say it only sets focus if the widget is in the active window. Have you tried this method to make sure the QTextEdit is the active window? http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#activateWindow

Comment: @Bradley T. Hughes - I tried it. But never worked me. I have attached for reference !

Answer (score 2):

You should pass the underlying document of the text editor i.e. `txt->document()` to the constructor of `QTextCursor` before you can use `QTextCursor` to do anything on `QTextEdit`. I guess it makes `QTextCursor` see it as a document. Then you use `QTextCursor` to insert the text into `QTextEdit` and also position the cursor where you want by using `beginEditBlock()` after inserting the text or `movePosition(QTextCursor::End)`.

```
#include <QLabel>
#include <QFont>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QTextCursor>
#include <QLineEdit>

int main( int argc, char **argv ) {
    QApplication app( argc, argv );

    MainWindow w;
    w.setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    w.setStyleSheet("background-color: yellow;");


    QTextEdit *txt = new QTextEdit();
    txt->setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    txt->setFocus();
    txt->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255,      200);");
    txt->setGeometry(10,20,100,30);


    QTextCursor cursor = QTextCursor(txt->document());
    cursor.insertText("Text 1");
    cursor.beginEditBlock();
    // OR
    //In your case, either methods below will work since the text has been inserted already
    //cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::End);
    //cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::Start);

    txt->show();

    return app.exec();
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Not working still. There is no cursor I can see. Here is the image :

Comment: really? I tested this code and the cursor appears right after "Text 1". Weird!

Comment: I've added an image of what i get after running the code

Comment: If I click on Textbox manually I get the curosr, else there is no cursor right after "Text 1". I am running this on a Embedded Hardware board and cross compile works fine too.

Comment: Or try typing something on the device and see if what you typed appeared after "text 1"

Comment: Not at all working !  There is not cursor. But thank you for quick solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78506/discussion-between-nana-osaberima-and-vk41286).